# ¿Por qué se "castigan" a los votantes negativos en las respuestas malas?

Tags: discusión, reputación, respuesta, votos

En primer lugar quiero decir que no soy un cazador de reputaciones ni me duele cuando me quitan reputaciones. (*Si fuese dinero sería otro tema*).

Hace mas o menos un mes que estoy otra vez activo en **SOes** y me da la sensación que el sitio va de mal en peor. No solo por las preguntas mal formadas, sino más bien por las **respuestas** dadas, perdiendo así cada vez más la esencia del padre **SOen**.

Pero vamos al grano:

Se ve que algunos apuestan por dar una repuesta tipo:

- soy adivino y respondo
- pongo este trozo de código **sin comprobar si funciona o no** y a ver lo que pasa
- copio una respuesta anterior y la redacto diferente, que por participar me votan también a favor
- soy guay, **sé de todo** y como aquí apenas hay votos negativos, respondo, que seguro habrá alguien con menos conocimiento aún y me vota a favor

...etc...etc...etc

*Me reservo de poner ejemplos de las respuestas, más que nada para no ofender a nadie.*

Si somos todos tan buenos como creemos, porque no se votan las respuestas *malas* en contra, igual como a las preguntas mal formadas?

**¿¿Por qué se pierde un punto de su valiosa reputación??**

En los casos de los *vampiros de las reputaciones*, si os fijáis en los perfiles, tienen los `votos emitidos`, `reportes útiles` y/o `ediciones` prácticamente nulos y luego dejan algunos comentarios para educar a los nuevos usuarios del sitio y se creen que con eso han ayudado a la comunidad. Pues no...

Yo diría...

*(ya que la idea básica de este sitio no es copiar 1:1 al original (SOen))*

...que seria bueno de **repensar** un sistema diferente, para a los que temen de perder reputaciones por votar en contra a las **respuestas claramente malas**...

> ...y que sean que reciban una recompensa, ej. medallas, privilegios etc!

Ejemplos para destacar *malas* preguntas:

**Votar en contra y reportar a las respuestas:**

- Repetitivas (similar a las preguntas duplicadas) y sin aportar nada nuevo de las respuestas anteriores
- De baja calidad, solo links, copiado 1:1 y/o traducido 1:1 de otros sitios
- Respondidas sin saber lo que el OP realmente quiere

Apuesto a lo que sea, que el sitio SOes, por ayudar/recompensar y no *castigar* a los que realmente aportan/saben, aumentaría la calidad notablemente de este sitio.

Comment: *Si somos todos tan buenos como creemos, porque no se votan las respuestas malas en contra, igual como a las preguntas mal formadas?* si es de un tema del que conozco p.e. [tag:java] o [tag:mysql] y veo una respuesta mala la voto en negativo y usualmente agrego un comentario. Si es sobre temas que desconozco, lo dejo allí porque siento que no tengo la autoridad moral para opinar sobre temas que no sé.

Comment: Yo pienso que sin datos no se puede controlar. En este caso, dices que omites ejemplos, pero en realidad analizar esos ejemplos reforzaría lo que comentas y ayudaría a demás usuarios en la comunidad a evitar ese tipo de respuestas. Sino, sigue siendo sonido en el aire muy abstracto.

Comment: Sobre el reporte de respuestas, tener en cuenta que puede que la respuesta sea válida pero técnicamente está equivocada. Este tipo de reportes son **rechazados**. Para los reportes de respuestas, referirnos a [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/958/227)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Siendo moderador del sitio se debería saber cuando esta **mal formada** una **pregunta** o **respuesta**, digo yo... Porque tendrás que revisar todos los reportes -  da igual sobre que tema -... y por eso mismo he dicho: *...los que realmente saben...* deberían: **Votar en contra** y/o **reportar**... Y  a los ejemplos omitidos: Si uno sabe del tema habrá visto un montón de ejemplos tal cual como lo describo... por eso evito de ofender a esas personas...

Comment: Sin ejemplos no se dice nada. Tu punto de vista sobre respuestas mal formadas puede variar del mío y lo digo porque usualmente los reportes de respuestas que veo son de problemas técnicos y no de respuestas mal formuladas. Nuevamente, sin ejemplos no comprendo a qué te refieres. Y no hablo de las respuestas troll o de solo enlace.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Lo que digo es una idea para mejorar el sitio en el sentido de calidad... Me gustaría que sea **SOes** una referencia con nivel parecido o igual al **SOen**... Y sigo diciendo que no hace falta poner ejemplos... Lo usuarios temen de perder reputaciones por una respuesta mala... y por eso no votan...y como son rechazadas porque técnicamente son validas... ahí se queda la respuesta *mala* y al fin al cabo recibe solo votos a favor... y la calidad se cae en el abismo... Repito: Quitar los **castigos** a las respuestas y se verá mas respuestas con votos negativos...

Comment: No estoy en contra ni a favor del -1 por votar negativo las respuestas, pero sí es verdad que muchas de las respuestas recientemente son "cualquier cosa". Muy buena pregunta, me cuestionaba si era el único que pensaba lo mismo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Si quieres un ejemplo actual: [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34790/problema-al-insertar-en-la-base-de-datos)... mira también la respuesta aceptada...y la única respuesta (de las 3 actualmente) mas o menos aceptable [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34791/6491) no tiene ningún voto... ahí lo dejo...

Comment: @aldanux nuevamente, todas esas lucen como respuestas con errores técnicos, pero cumplen con el estándar de respuesta aceptable para el sitio. Y no veo ningún voto negativo, lo cual me dice que ni siquiera tú que propones realizar el voto negativo estás a favor de votarlas negativamente a pesar que piensas que deberías hacerlo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - no he votado a voto negativo para que veas si no lo hago yo no lo hace **nadie**!

Comment: Ya te dije, **yo** voto a negativo en aquellas publicaciones que creo que están mal. El voto a favor/en contra es una decisión personal. Si pides que otros también voten en contra cuando vean respuestas que no son buenas, podrías comenzar votando tú primero, dando el ejemplo.

Comment: @Shaz vota en contra. Para eso está hecho el sistema de votos. Si piensas que algo está mal y no votas en contra, estás contribuyendo con el problema al no hacer nada al respecto.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza lo hago generalmente :) no tengo problema en perder un punto cada vez que lo hago, solo que algunas veces tendría que ser en "casi" todas las respuestas de una pregunta.

Comment: @Shaz eso me sucede a menudo cuando reviso la etiqueta [java] pero son más los puntos que acumulo que los que pierdo, así que no tengo miedo de perder la reputación por votar en contra (hasta que se me acaban los votos)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - creo que no me entiendes bien... **Yo solo** no puedo mejorar el sitio... más quisiera yo... pero para los *cazadores de reputaciones* y demás que no quieren perder un punto de su ego seria bueno de **reinventar** el sistema de los "castigos"... una vez más: para mejorar el sitio...

Comment: **Yo solo** tampoco puedo mejorar el sitio, por eso **somos una comunidad**. Si hay publicaciones que **tú sientes** que están mal formuladas, entonces repórtalas para que los moderadores las revisemos. Pero si ves publicaciones que encajan dentro de "aceptable" **pero** presentan errores técnicos, **puedes votar en contra**. Si veo una publicación con votos en contra, la reviso y veo si realmente debe tener mi voto en contra. Avisar a los demás miembros de la comunidad a **no tener miedo a votar en contra** me parece bueno, pero este sistema es de toda la red de StackExchange, no solo de aquí

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza +1 - Perfecto... espero y deseo que **la comunidad* cambie en un futuro a mejor...

Comment: [Aquí una pregunta/respuesta relacionada](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1075/227) . Buscaré otra del MSE más asociada con lo que preguntas.

Comment: Ya encontré lo que preguntas: [aquí](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146460/182862) y [aquí](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62130/182862). La segunda es mucho más antigua y era cuando votar en contra a las preguntas también costaba 1 de reputación tal como se explica en [esta publicación](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90324/182862).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Excelente...muchas gracias por el trabajo que haz hecho y por las informaciones

Answer (score 9):

En mi opinión, creo que la respuesta es simple.

El "castigo" de -1 punto de reputación existe para evitar que los usuarios voten en contra sólo para perjudicar a algún usuario en particular, o para que su propia respuesta tenga más visibilidad o porque simplemente estaba enojado con el mundo y quiso votar en contra.

Un punto en negativo tiende a lograr con bastante éxito evitar que el voto en contra se use "porque sí", pero prácticamente no tiene significancia en tu rep (es sólo un punto, lejos de ser realmente relevante).

Por estos motivos, no veo el problema en que exista este -1, es más, estoy de acuerdo completamente con que sea de esta forma.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, es muy simple y necesario este -1 para evitar el abuso y para que haya cierto compromiso con el motivo del voto.

Comment: de hecho hay una medalla por votar a favor en respuestas a una pregunta donde tu tambien has respondido (no recuerdo el nombre ^^' )

Comment: @lois6b http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship

Comment: el voto negativo esta bien para que las respuestas malas queden debajo, pero para evitar que los usuarios voten negativo con el fin de perjudicar a otro usuario o para hacer su propia respuesta mas visible como dices, debería de exigirse que el votante argumente por que razón considera la respuesta mala...