# ¿Por qué hay tanta condescendencia a la hora de votar? ¿Es correcto?

Tags: discusión, votos

Cuando inicié en Stack Overflow lo hice en la versión en inglés porque no había en español, pero hace poco me uní a esta comunidad hispana. Pero hay demasiada flexibilidad en dos casos (se usa mucho el voto a favor, pero casi nunca el voto en contra):

- Cuando se hace una pregunta

  - He notado que hay votos a favor a pesar de que la pregunta no corresponde a la descripción.
  - No hay datos suficientes para responder.
  - Hay demasiadas preguntas off-topic.
  - Piden código completo.
  - La pregunta es demasiado genérica y no especifica en absoluto el problema real
- Cuando se responde a una pregunta

  - La respuesta es código que no funciona.
  - La respuesta no responde la pregunta dada.

Este tipo de fallas son muy castigadas en la versión en inglés, pero aquí no. ¿Es correcto? Viendo esto futuro, no hay referencias para marcar una pregunta como  duplicada por que la pregunta inicial no corresponde al contenido de lo que se pregunta y llevaría el sitio a una caída en su calidad.

¿Cuál sería la conducta recomendada por parte de la comunidad para prevenir y mejorar este tipo de conductas?

He visto comentarios relacionados a la baja calidad de las preguntas:
[¿Por qué se “castigan” a los votantes negativos en las respuestas malas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1073/23233), [Stack Overflow ES se está convirtiendo en el Rincón del Vago?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1090/23233), por lo que me preocupa que la calidad del sitio decrezca.

Comment: De acuerdísimo contigo. Estoy en el mismo caso, me parece que hay demasiadas malas preguntas, y gente con mucha reputación contestándolas. No se cuál es el espíritu de esto, pero parece que sólo quieren más puntos y no mejorar la calidad del sitio. Y para acabarla, cuando quieres dejarles claras las reglas sobre todo a los más nuevos, se enojan y te tachan de "nazi", o eres víctima del downvote serial. Estoy a favor de endurecer un poco las normas de flaggeo, y sobre todo de tratar con ciertos usuarios "con reputación" a que empiecen a contribuir a la causa.

Comment: Yo me llegué a comer un voto negativo por ser muy cálido para escribir, siempre empiezo saludando, y siempre termino agradeciendo y saludando (agregando un "abrazo" o alguna cara feliz). El 100% de las veces alguien me edita la pregunta/respuesta sacando esas cosas, como si el material perdiese calidad.

Además, me parece mas que claro que hay una diferencia notable entre la comunidad hispana y la no-hispana. Como que la hispana tiende a ser mas cálida y mediocre, salvando las excepciones, que normalmente son personas que andan en SOen también.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hace poco escribí una pregunta aquí en el sitio sobre los votos, y es muy clara sobre este tema. La pregunta en sí: [¿Cuándo debería votar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1075/227)

Fuera de eso, mi opinión es y siempre será respecto a la **calidad** de la publicación:

- Para las preguntas, **si ves que realmente no apoya al sitio o no tiene la calidad suficiente, le votes en contra**.
- Para las respuestas, **piensa si realmente es una respuesta con contenido malo, de baja calidad o si no responde a la pregunta**. En esos casos, **vota en contra**. Que el puntaje negativo requerido para votar en contra **no sea una limitante**.

Mi única *limitante* en este caso es la experiencia del dueño de la publicación en el sitio. Si es un usuario nuevo, usualmente no voto en contra, suelo dejar comentarios constructivos para que pueda comprender mejor cómo publicar contenido de calidad. Si es un usuario medio/experimentado, mi interacción cambia. Para más información, revisar [Veo muchas publicaciones malas y me enoja muchísimo. ¿Qué debo hacer al respecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/615/227)

---

Considero que una respuesta es aceptable para el sitio si tiene los siguientes elementos:

- Propuesta de solución
- Explicación concisa de la solución
- Puede que muestre código (en caso de resolver una excepción) o pseudocódigo (por ejemplo, para explicar una tarea y no resolver el ejercicio).

A pesar de ello, si una respuesta tiene todos estos elementos pero

- El código es incorrecto o genera más problemas
- El contenido lleva a una sobre ingeniería, es decir, hacer mucho para resolver algo muy simple. Clásico caso de usar una bazuca para matar un insecto.
- Luce como un muy buen tutorial para aprender de X pero el problema se trata de Y. Ejemplo: tengo un problema con una sentencia JavaScript `document.getElementById()` y publico un tutorial de introducción a jQuery con `$(':id')` y demás. Sin embargo, no cubre el problema del OP al usar `document.getElementById()`.

Entonces la respuesta, para mí, es una **respuesta aceptable de baja calidad** y debo votarla en contra. Pero **no significa** que deba reportarla a un moderador. Los moderadores verán la publicación y no la eliminarán.

Para respuestas que simplemente son malas, ya existe una guía al respecto: [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/958/227)

Comment: Muy de acuerdo. Sobretodo en la parte de "tengo un problema con Javascript y me contestan con JQuery". Como odio que hagan eso, aunque respondan bien, les doy negativo por no ceñirse a las especificaciones de la pregunta y porque usar una librería para un problema pequeño no es la solución.

Comment: Una pregunta: cuando mencionas los tres puntos para votar a favor, ¿te refieres a que tiene que cumplir los tres o uno solo de ellos?

Comment: @fedorqui en ninguna parte menciono puntos para votar a favor de algo, mi publicación se concentra en cómo votar en contra y una explicación de cómo decido votar en contra a las respuestas. Quizás te refieres a los 3 puntos de lo que considero una respuesta aceptable, pero quiero separar el hecho de que una respuesta puede lucir aceptable para el sitio pero ser mala.

Comment: Luiggi: no me expresé bien, me refiero al enunciado _Considero que una respuesta es aceptable para el sitio si tiene los siguientes elementos_. En él, ¿te refieres a que una pregunta aceptable debe tener todos los elementos que describes o al menos uno?

Comment: @fedorqui esos puntos son para la respuesta aceptable, no para una pregunta aceptable. Una pregunta aceptable tiene diversos parámetros, dependiendo de lo que se enfoca la pregunta, no es lo mismo evaluar una pregunta de programación que una pregunta de diseño de software o que una pregunta sobre diseño de algoritmos.

Comment: Que raro leerte sin el diamante

Answer (score 0):

Totalmente de acuerdo con Mendoza.

Pero quiero añadir que otro motivo para la ausencia de votos negativos es que en esta comunidad, y en el mundo latino en general, somos menos imparciales, personalizamos más y nos tomamos como ataque personal lo que es una crítica a nuestro escrito no a nuestra persona. Por supuesto esto no es para todo el mundo, pero es una tendencia notable.

Si votas negativo a alguien y además te delatas añadiendo un comentario a tu voto negativo (que es lo honesto) con frecuencia te puedes encontrar con votos de represalia. No lo hace todo el mundo, pero sucede, y más que en el sitio en inglés. Resultado, o no se vota negativo, o si se vota se hace sin poner el motivo.

Véase por ejemplo lo que sucede en esta pregunta (si tienes puntuación suficiente para ver respuestas borradas) : [Tengo problemas con ciertas librerias C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36501/tengo-problemas-con-ciertas-librerias-c#36518). No es la primera vez.

Answer (score 0):

Yo en lo personal no soy de esas personas que dan votos negativos, sólo lo hice una vez.

Yo preferiría indicarle en qué está fallando si conozco del tema que pregunta. De lo contrario omito la pregunta, y que sea otro quien reporte o aplique downvote

Todos estamos aquí para aprender y hasta el más experto puede fallar, así que no consideres que estás siendo muy correcto con tu forma de pensar y que digas que los que *somos condescendientes* estamos mal, cada quien tiene su forma de pensar y opinar.

Sea lo que sea que suceda en StackOverflow Inglés no debería importarnos, y si tanto quieres que seamos como StackOverflow Inglés, entonces deberías empezar por decirle a los usuarios que simplemente porque no entienden la pregunta a su modo, empiezan a reportar y he notado varios casos donde algunos reportan **simplemente** porque otros lo están haciendo. Así como también a preguntas tan pequeñas la comunidad inglesa suele tener amplias respuestas, que responden la pregunta, hacen recomendaciones y agregan datos adicionales que puedan servir para continuar el proceso de lo que sea que esté en desarrollo.

Hay algunos a los que les gusta hacer todo y entregarlo resuelto, a otros les gusta que el usuario intente mostrar lo que tiene, hay personas de personas y eso **tiene que ser respetable en todo sentido**.

Tú eres como eres, así también somos como somos.

Antes de ver cómo está StackOverflow Inglés date cuenta que somos otra comunidad, somos diferentes, lo único igual es la página.

Comment: ¿Y si hay una respuesta claramente errónea, con votos positivos y que tú sabes a ciencia cierta que es mala y que la gente se la está creyendo a pies juntillas? Votar negativamente sirve para eso: para destacar lo bueno y esconder lo malo y así ayudar a los que visiten la página en el futuro.

Comment: @fedorqui yo estoy hablando de las preguntas, en el caso de las respuestas, solo daria un voto negativo si tengo la verdadera respuesta.

Answer (score -4):

Voy a contestar todas las preguntas en orden.

#### En el título

1. Porque cuando votas negativo te quitan un punto, y como a mi me cuesta mucho ganarlos no quiero perderlos.
2. Claro que es correcto. Como no hay forma de obligar a los usuarios a votar negativo cuando otro usuario piensa que una pregunta debe votarse negativo, pues queda a criterio personal. Además no es posible saber (a menos que seas El Moderador) quién vota positivo o negativo, no hay forma de comentarle al votante que está siendo condescendiente.

#### En el contenido

1. Claro que es correcto. SOes no es lo mismo que SE, ni en antigüedad ni en volumen de preguntas. No podemos comportarnos igual.
2. Vive y deja vivir.

Comment: Se supone que la comunidad, ademas de ser una herramienta para los desarrolladores, también tiene otros beneficios (sino, no habría mucho sentido en tomarse la molestia para responder). En SOen están los jobs. Si estas adscrito a una comunidad donde se responden preguntas de baja calidad (y que requieren bajo nivel de conocimiento) entonces la reputación no sirve de nada por que no cuesta trabajo ganársela. La credibilidad de la comunidad en español es baja y no es un tema de querer o no, mas bien de responsabilidad.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo contigo. (_Aunque a mi me ha costado mucho ganarme mis puntitos._)

Comment: Se supone que el objetivo de este sitio es crear una comunidad de programadores de habla hispana. No la de ganar puntos. Si realizas buenas respuestas, los puntos vendrán solos.

Comment: Yo no supongo nada... Y  la parte lúdica es muy importante en toda la Red SE, no se puede negar la importancia ni de los puntos ni de las medallas.

Comment: En este caso, creo que se trata más de un "vivo con miedo a perder mi reputación porque me cuesta ganarla así que no votaré en contra, mi reputación es valiosa, y dejo que los demás vivan tranquilos pensando que publicando cosas de baja calidad aportan al sitio y a la comunidad".

Comment: Otra cosa, ni siquiera los moderadores podemos saber quién vota a favor/en contra en una publicación. Eso es injusto para los demás usuarios.

Comment: Exacto, Luiggi. Ese ese es mi caso. PD, yo solo voto negativo las preguntas de Omar Omar, nada mas.

Comment: Viendo todos estos comentarios, explico mi -1, ya que no es por las mismas razones: Me pasó lo mismo en otras comunidades, donde me cuesta mucho cada punto, pero no coincido en que sea el mayor motivo de lo que el autor llama "condecendencia", y creo que un buen tema a plantear es "*cómo profesionalizar SOes para evolucionar en puntajes de publicaciones*"... Es decir, estoy de acuerdo con parte de tu respuesta, pero no como respuesta a *esta* pregunta.

Comment: Pues claro que no es lo mismo, porque yo no generalizo mi respuesta. Hablo por mi. No creo que haya una razón general que explica el comportamiento, pero por lo menos en mi caso, puedo explicar el mio.

Comment: @toledano Tenés razón. Cuando lo leí pensé que estabas generalizando, pero al releerla, me di cuenta que sólo era tu punto de vista y que la había interpretado mal.