# Manejar situaciones, consideracion con usuarios nuevos que responden

Tags: discusión, votos, usuarios-nuevos, respuesta, votos-negativos

Bien no es la primera vez que veo casos similares, en los que usuarios nuevos contestan a preguntas que no son bien recibidas en el sito, y estos reciben -1 sin ninguna explicación.

---

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83859/c%C3%A1lculo-de-divisa

- **Pregunta** -2
- **Respuesta 1** -3
- **Respuesta 2** -4

---

Pienso que esto no es justo para el usuari@ que intenta ayudar con una respuesta, y no solo no recibee +1 por ello sino que obtiene -1 sin ninguna explicación, creo que esto no es bueno de cara a que más personas se integren en la comunidad aportando lo que puedan.

Esto no va enfocado a los "listos" que dan menos uno sin explicación, bueno aunque quizás alguno recapacite. Es para los que creamos que esta práctica no es buena para el sito podamos "debatir" cómo se puede abordar estos casos.

---

Yo creo que aunque uno no sea el responsable de los downvotes, pero quizás por la experiencia en la red, pueda orientar al usuario que responde y tiene -1 de el porque de estos o algo similar.

---

Por otra parte:

- **Respuesta 1** -3
- **Respuesta 2** -4

En serio, hacen falta esas cantidades de down en las respuesta, casi que parece prepotencia y mala leche, quizas "uno" se podría llegar a entender pero tantos que se consigue con eso aparte de espantar a los usuarios que intentan integrarse en el sitio.

---

**UPDATE:**

> No se puede comentar sobre el tema, porque la pregunta fue eliminada
>   :(.. esto quedo como un sinsentido, ojala huberian copiado la pregunta
>   y las respuestas aca para poder dar un punto de vista mejor. – gbianch

gbianch gracias por su interes en el link de abajo la puede ver:

[pregunta/respuestas](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WdqrM4Fp3NYJ:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83859/c%25C3%25A1lculo-de-divisa+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=es)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61613/discussion-on-question-by-angel-angel-manejar-situaciones-consideracion-con-usu).

Answer (score 5):

Tengo varios días en lo que por momentos he pensado comentar algo como lo siguiente. Para no darle más largas, aprovecho que esta pregunta se mencionó en el chat.

---

Podría pensarse que tenemos dos objetivos contradictorios:

1. Tratar bien a los nuevos usuarios
2. Participar en el sitio

Con respecto al primero algunos miembros de la comunidad "asumen" que los usuarios nuevos se van sentir ofendidos porque reciben votos negativos, esto basado en experiencias personales y más importante aún porque algunos usuarios nuevos lo han externado y no han vuelto y otros usuarios luego de dejar de ser nuevos han compartido sus impresiones.

Con respecto al segundo, una parte fundamental de la participación en el sitio es el votar, tanto así que uno de los privilegios que requiren la pocos puntos de reputación es el de votar positivo, tan sólo se requieren 15 y para votar negativo tan sólo 125 (véase [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/65)).

En lo personal lo que hago con frecuencia es dar una "**tregua**" de votos negativos y de cierre a las preguntas que podrían arreglarse y que tienen menos de una hora o en ocasiones hasta de un día.

Preguntas relacionadas en orden cronológico:

- [¿Qué actitud es adecuada para estimular la buena calidad de preguntas y respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/201/65)
- [Falta de "participación"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/941/65)
- [¿Por qué se "castigan" a los votantes negativos en las respuestas malas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1073/65)

Comment: me parece bien su forma de actuar, deje un comentario a @Pikoh para que se notara la diferencia entre las preguntas buenas con respuestas malas, y las preguntas fuera de lugar, (si quiere lo puede leer).

Comment: Por otro lado en lo personal las respuestas tratada en cuestion me parece como dije mas cosa de prepotencia y mala leche "por no usar otros terminos" que otra cosa, gracias por exponer su forma de actuar ect. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo que te refieres a que no es una conducta adecuada, pero no lo llamaría con esos términos, sin embargo, todavía no tengo claro como llamarles. Lo que se me viene a la mente son frases como "hacer leña del árbol caído"

Comment: Pero entonces, ¿cuál es la recomendación? ¿"Vota pronto y con frecuencia" excepto en el caso de las preguntas que consideres malas que podrían arreglarse? En todo caso, ¿podría ser que "si una respuesta se considera mala y ya tiene un voto y el usuario es recién llegado, entonces ya no se agreguen más votos negativos"?

Comment: @toledano: No me siento listo todavía para dar una recomendación ni para hacer una propuesta que concilie el "Vota pronto y con frecuencia" con la sensibilidad que se asume tienen los usuarios nuevos hacia los votos negativos a lo que se suma el asunto que trae Angel de "no hacer bola contra los usuarios nuevos". Por otro lado está lo que comenta Pikoh en los comentarios a la pregunta con respecto a que muchos de los usuarios con +125 no pasan por Meta. Si me urges a dar una recomendación provisional, yo diría no votar negativo a las preguntas 
 "salvables"  con menos de un día.

Comment: La recomendación es: trata a los demás como te gustaría que te tratasen a ti.